# In python3, the value returned by multiple calls to hexgigest is different

Tags: python-3.x, hashlib

In python3, the value returned by multiple calls to hexgigest is different.why, I don't understand?thanks

```
In [1]: import hashlib

In [2]: s=hashlib.sha1()

In [3]: s.update('v3'.encode('utf8'))

In [4]: s.hexdigest()
Out[4]: 'c5e31d5915661de4393e3f1489b00ebc4497dd48'

In [5]: s.update('v3'.encode('utf8'))

In [6]: s.hexdigest()
Out[6]: '478fb161514c3e8b395c9968e042ab214a98d0d8'
```

Comment: The `.update()` method does not override your previous input. You're basically doing `s.update('v3v3'.encode('utf8'))`

Comment: haha，thank you，i got it

Answer (score 1):

Please [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hashlib.html?highlight=hashlib#hashlib.hash.update):

> Repeated calls [to `update`] are equivalent to a single call with the concatenation of all the arguments: `m.update(a); m.update(b)` is equivalent to `m.update(a+b)`.